# SQL Server index advice performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, indexing

I'm looking for some advice to how to get the indexes running better on this query...
SQL Server 2005/8 some customers have 5 some 8...

```
SELECT    sales.ChainStoreId, 
          sales.CashBoxId, 
          dbo.DateOnly2(sales.BonDate), 
          MAX(sales.BonDate), 
          SUM(sales.SumPrice) 
FROM      [BACK_CDM_CLEAN_BOLTEN].[dbo].[CashBoxSales] sales
WHERE     sales.BonType in ('B','P','W')             
AND       Del = 0 
AND       sales.BonDate >= @minDate
GROUP BY  sales.ChainStoreId, 
          sales.CashBoxId, 
          dbo.DateOnly2(sales.BonDate)
```

Table looks like the following

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CashBoxSales](
    [SalesRowId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ChainStoreId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CashBoxId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [BonType] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [BonDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [BonNr] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [SumPrice] [money] NOT NULL,
    [Discount] [money] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeId] [int] NULL,
    [DayOfValidity] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ProcStatus] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Del] [int] NOT NULL,
    [InsertedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [LastUpdate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
```

What would be the correct ordering of the index columns, covered or composite etc. 
The table has up to 10 mil rows. There are other similar selects but I'm hoping from the advice getting this one up to speed (Its the most important) I can tweak a few others.

Many thanks!

Comment: I should have added that the Del column only has value 0,1 and the bontype has around 5 values. The Dateonly2 function returns a date given a datetime, should I make a deterministic column index (?). I also know about the profiler, analyzer and DTA etc. Would rather have principled answers, based on logic than tools...cheers

Comment: OK I have the thing down to under 2 seconds using the advisor and the index 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Alex_index_] ON [dbo].[CashBoxSales] 
(
 [BonType] ASC,
 [Del] ASC,
 [BonDate] ASC,
 [ChainStoreId] ASC,
 [CashBoxId] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [SumPrice]) 

Now who can explain to me why the thing is in this order and why an index on del 2 values, Bontype 3 values, helps...I understand the bondate and i understand the sumprice in the include, no extra lookup is needed and all columns necessary are there but.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have your query in SQL Server Management Studio, just select "Analyze Query in Database Tuning Advisor" from the context menu, and off you go!

[image]

Mind you: this only tweaks this one single query in isolation! Adding indices here to speed this one query up might adversely affect other parts of your application. An index always comes with overhead - inserts and deletes tend to be slower.

Also, don't blindly implement all the recommendations of the DTA - use your own judgment as to whether an index makes sense or not.

And lastly: measure, measure, measure! Measure your performance before any changes as a baseline, then measure again and again after you've made the changes and compare.

Comment: Currently looking a good answer as it has led to the correct answer...now I need to understand why...

Answer (score 0):

My best advice is to run this query through the SQL Profiler.  It will recommend some indexes for you to try.

Also, you might try setting up a partitioned table and use one of your GROUP BY columns as the partitioning key.

Answer (score 0):

**Off the top of my head** I would start with

```
INDEX (BonType, Del, BonDate)
```

Or even just

```
INDEX (BonType, BonDate)
```

*I would recomend using an Index Analyzer, Proflier and Benchmarking various combinations.*